# Recursive Scan To Move All Files And Deleting Empty Directories

Tags: bash, scripts

I am learning bash scripting and want to move all *.ort files to a new directory and delete the directory once the .ort file is moved.

To Note:

1. I do not need to keep same structure - I want to move to a single directory that contains all .ort files
2. I can delete the directory once the file is moved as it contains only a .ort file and nothing else

I think this will work, but wanted to confirm before I Just run bash scripting on a directory.

Syntax:

```
find / -iname "*.ort" -type d -exec /bin/mv {} /home/user123/Desktop/movedfiles/ \;
rmdir **/*/;
```

I welcome all suggestions and feedback for improvements or if this will work :)

Comment: Is this for learning purposes or functionality? A problem you'd have to face anyway is how to hanldle similarly named files.

Comment: @JacobVlijm - functionality.  Will be a script run 2 a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ort' -exec mv -i {} outdir \; -exec bash -c 'rmdir "${1%/*}"' _ {} \;
```

- `find . -type f -name '*.ort' -exec mv -i {} outdir \;` will move the only `.ort` file from the source directory to target directory (`outdir`)
- The second `-exec` action, `-exec bash -c 'rmdir "${1%/*}"' _ {} \;` will only run if the previous `-exec` action succeeds i.e. `.ort` file is found and moved successfully. You can put it under one `-exec` too with `&&` but two `-exec`s are used to make things a bit cleaner.
- The second `-exec` action will just remove the empty directory which was containing the file; `${1%/*}` is bash parameter expansion pattern to get the directory name, `dirname` would work too.

**Example:**

```
$ tree
.
├── egg
├── ortdir1
│   └── foo.ort
├── ortdir2
│   └── bar.ort
├── outdir
└── spam

$ find . -type f -name '*.ort' -exec mv -i {} outdir \; -exec bash -c 'rmdir "${1%/*}"' _ {} \;

$ tree
.
├── egg
├── outdir
│   ├── bar.ort
│   └── foo.ort
└── spam
```

Comment: will it cause any hiccups if I use a full location i.e. replace outdir with /home/abcd/Desktop/ready4review

Comment: @HabibInman Nothing at all..